# Pandas column to row transformation for a Range

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am looking to transform the below df based on the range from range(merge_m,merge_end,merge_freq)

```
data={'cf':['cf1','cf2'],'Amount':['1000','2000'],
     'merge_m':['1','3'],
     'merge_end':['4','5'],
     'merge_freq':['1','2']}
       
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I am looking to convert this into:

```
data_f={'m':[1,2,3,4,5],
        'cf1':['1000','1000','1000','1000',0],
         'cf2':[0,0,'2000',0,'2000']}
df_f=pd.DataFrame(data_f)
```

Comment: Could you explain the rationale behind the convertion? For example, why in the transformed dataframe m=3 has cf1=1000 and cf2=2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this question, assuming I interpreted it correctly:

```py
# convert to numeric dtypes:
df = df.transform(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")

# generate ranges based on the last three columns:
ranges = zip(df.merge_m, df.merge_end + df.merge_freq, df.merge_freq)
ranges = [
    range(start, end, freq)
    for start, end, freq in ranges
 ]

# Compute new dataframe:
(df
.loc[:, ["cf", "Amount"]]
.assign(m=ranges)
.explode("m")
.pivot( "m", "cf", "Amount")
.fillna(0, downcast="infer")
.rename_axis(columns=None)
.reset_index()
)

   m   cf1   cf2
0  1  1000     0
1  2  1000     0
2  3  1000  2000
3  4  1000     0
4  5     0  2000
```